# NSURL getting value from string

Tags: iphone, url, nsurl

I have the following string that I am passing into `[NSURL URLWithString:]` and getting `nil` back.

I do not see anything wrong with the string??

```
/Users/danny/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/A7C18F62-6ED3-4193-993B-D724ADA4D292/fantasy.app/common/files/file1/movies/demo1.mov
```

Am I mistaken?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [+fileURLWithPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath%3a) method, it should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:yourString]
```